# how to display file input buttons multiple times with image preview?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working with laravel 5.6 and I have image upload button with my form. currently it is using upload single file with image thumbnail preview.

```
<h3>Upload  images</h3>
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
```

jquery

```
<script >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
            $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
                var files = e.target.files,
                filesLength = files.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
                    var f = files[i]
                    var fileReader = new FileReader();
                    fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
                        var file = e.target;
                        $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
                          "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
                          "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Remove image</span>" +
                          "</span>").insertAfter("#files");
                        $(".remove").click(function() {
                            $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
                        });
                    });
                    fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
        }
    });
</script>
```

css

```
input[type="file"] {
  display: block;
}
.imageThumb {
  max-height: 75px;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.pip {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.remove {
  display: block;
  background: #444;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.remove:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

now I add another upload input to same form like this,

```
<div class="form-group row required">
    <div class="field" align="left" >
        <h3>Upload  images</h3>
        <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
        <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />//new one
    </div>
</div>
```

Then first upload button can appear image thumbnail but second file input did not display thumbnails. What is the problem? How can fix this problem?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with `then first upload button can appear image thumbanail but second file input did not display thumbanails` /facepalm

Comment: Might be related to the fact that you gave both buttons the same `id`.  Every HTML element must have a unique `id`.

Comment: **then first upload button can appear image thumbanail but second file input did not display thumbnails** it means first file input button can display with image thumbnail but second images upload input buttons can attach images but did not display image thumbnails

Comment: then may I change jquery updates according to the id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of giving both buttons the same `id` (any id that you give must be unique), give them the same `class` that you can then reference in your Javascript.

```
<div class="form-group row required">
    <div class="field" align="left" >
        <h3>Upload  images</h3>
        <input type="file" class="files" name="files[]" multiple />
        <input type="file" class="files" name="files[]" multiple />//new one
    </div>
</div>
```

Then your Javascript needs to be updated to bind the listener based on class instead of id.  The `.insertAfter()` also gets updated to refer to the specific item clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    $(".files").on("change", function(e) {  // THIS LINE CHANGED
        var clickedButton = this;  // THIS LINE IS NEW
        var files = e.target.files,
        filesLength = files.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
          var f = files[i]
          var fileReader = new FileReader();

          fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
            var file = e.target;
            $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
            "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
            "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Remove image</span>" +
            "</span>").insertAfter(clickedButton);  // THIS LINE CHANGED

            $(".remove").click(function(){
              $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
            });
          });

          fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    });
  } else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
  }
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/201339/)